# Simultaneous display of two animations in SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I'm trying to get two animations to show at the same time. The application builds successfully but crashes in the emulator.

I have created an Anim class in a thread that handles the Animations in a while loop. I think there is a problem with my draw method but I cant seem to figure it out.

I appreciate any help on this, thank you

### Error Log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myproject/com.example.myproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup
```

and

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
        at com.example.my_project.PlayActivity$surfaceView$Anim.run(PlayActivity.java:109)
```

### CODE

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
surfaceView view;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    view = new surfaceView(this);

    setContentView(view);



public class surfaceView extends SurfaceView {


    public surfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        new Anim().start();
    }


    private class Anim extends Thread {
        int counter = 0;
        int counter2 = 0;



        @Override
        public void run() {
            long last_updated_time = 0;
            long delay = 250;
            int[] purple_bird = {
                    R.drawable.bird1,
                    R.drawable.bird2
            };
            int[] red_bird = {
                    R.drawable.red1,
                    R.drawable.red2,
                    R.drawable.red3,
                    R.drawable.red4
            };


            while (true) {
                boolean playing = true;
                if (playing) {

                    long current_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (current_time > last_updated_time + delay) {
                        if ((counter >= 2) && (counter2 >= 4)) {
                            counter = 0;
                            counter2 = 0;


                        }
                        draw(purple_bird[counter], red_bird[counter2]);

                        last_updated_time = current_time;
                        counter++;
                        counter2++;
                    }
                }
            }




        }

        private void draw(int red_bird, int purple_bird) {

            SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

            if (canvas != null) {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                Paint paint = new Paint();

                Bitmap purpleBird = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), purple_bird);
                Bitmap redBird = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), red_bird);


                Bitmap resizedRedBird = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(redBird, (int) (redBird.getWidth() * 0.4), (int) (redBird.getHeight() * 0.4), true);
                Bitmap resizedPurpleBird = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(purpleBird, (int) (purpleBird.getWidth() * 0.2), (int) (purpleBird.getHeight() * 0.2), true);

                canvas.drawBitmap(resizedRedBird, 500, 500, paint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(resizedPurpleBird, 100, 100, paint);

                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);




            }

        }
    }





}
```

}

Comment: You have to implement the process-draw-input in one Thread. Extract the code where you move the Bird to a object, in your Thread have a collection of Birds and call in a loop first process(move and respond to user input), draw(draw everything in one canvas), input(toggle states of input so birds can read in process state)

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I have updated the code where I put everything into one thread with both animations being drawn in the same method on the same canvas but it crashes at runtime

Comment: Which exception? The stacktrace will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because accessing a SurfaceView (with Canvas) is exclusive, you cannot draw simultaneously to it.

```
holder.lockCanvas();

(...) // the canvas is locked during this

holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

So, your possible solution is to manipulate and draw both of red bird and blue bird in the same draw method (in between lock and unlock) of the same thread.

---

## Edit

For another error 2:

```
if ((counter >= 2) && (counter2 >= 4)) {
    counter = 0;
    counter2 = 0;
}
```

This condition is wrong. Because only when both of counter and counter2 excessed, they are reset. They should be separated:

```
if (counter >= 2) {
    counter = 0;
}
if (counter2 >= 4) {
    counter2 = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please find the updated code above.
I tried drawing both animations in the same draw method in between lock and unlock but the application now keeps crashing.

Comment: @Taipan Maybe another problem arises. Please edit your question again to add the respective error log.

Comment: I have updated the question now, I also figured I should deal with one problem at a time so I removed the SoundPool and OnClickListener from the code above, for now, to just show the code for my Animations

Comment: @Taipan That is very nice approach both for solving a problem by yourself and for asking a question on StackOverFlow :)

Comment: @Taipan And again, please show the error log to enable us to figure out your problem.

Comment: legend! that works like a charm! how would I go about adding separate OnClickListeners to each animation? Is it possible to set an OnClickListener to each bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

Drawing on a Surface has to be done USUALLY only from one Thread at a time.

If you want to draw from different Threads then you have to consider that "lockCanvas()" requires to upload ALL Surface pixels at each call, but you're just drawing each animation pixels without considering the other one. In this behaviour the "second" Thread will "override" the whole Surface pixels with only its own pixels and that's why you see a flickering effect.

I suggest you to use a common Bitmap where to draw on (and it will be the only Bitmap on which call "unlockCanvasAndPost()"), or just merge those two Threads in just one and handle both animations there.

Comment: I updated the code and put both animations in the same draw method in the same thread but the application now crashes. Im not quite sure what you mean by a common bitmap, don't I have to create separate bitmaps for both animations? how else would I manipulate size and position?
Thank you